# Return Folder path and filename recursively in python

Tags: python

How can I return just the folder leafs within the targeted directory when using os.walk in python.

Here is my function:

```
def get_files(directory):
    directory = os.path.abspath(directory)
    if not os.path.isdir(directory):
        return False

    files = []  
    for root, subdirs, files in os.walk(directory):
        for f in files:
            if not f.lower().endswith('.jpg'):
                continue

            print root, f

get_files('C:/Temp')
```

Which returns this:

```
C:\Temp\images socket.jpg
C:\Temp\images vexusrollout.jpg
C:\Temp\newdocs\images utilityrollout.jpg
C:\Temp\newdocs\images vexushelper.jpg
C:\Temp\newdocs\images vexusmtl.jpg
C:\Temp\newdocs\images vexusrollout.jpg
```

I'd prefer it return this:

```
images socket.jpg
images vexusrollout.jpg
newdocs\images utilityrollout.jpg
newdocs\images vexushelper.jpg
newdocs\images vexusmtl.jpg
newdocs\images vexusrollout.jpg
```

The main difference between whatever directory i target for looping through, i don't want that bit to be included in the output.

Comment: If you know which directory you are iterating through you could simply slice the string: `print root[9:], f`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change

```
print root, f
```

to

```
print root[len(directory)+1:], f
```